# Can I bold invididual elements in y_range of a bokeh chart?

Tags: text, label, bar-chart, bokeh, axis

I would like to bold some of the values in my y_range but not others.

I have tried using p.yaxis.major_label_text_font_style = 'bold'.  This bolds everything.  I have also tried setting it equal to a column in a ColumnDataSource, but major_label_text_font_style does not accept that as an input.

```
# Orient y axis labels
p.yaxis.major_label_text_font_size = '18pt'
p.yaxis[0].major_label_text_font_style = 'bold'
p.yaxis.major_label_text_font = "calibri"
```

I would like some of the text in my y_range to be bold, but not all of the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Bokeh 1.1 there is no built-in way to accomplish this. *[1]* The main reason is that, in general, tick labels and locations can be chosen dynamically, as a result of panning and zooming. There is no guarantee a tick you want to treat differently will actually be labeled or on the screen at all. I.e. it's not useful to say "make the third tick bold" if you have no idea of knowing or controlling what the third tick will be.

However, it might be possible to do something different in the case of categorical ticks, which are normally always all displayed, and so known up-front. I'd encourage you to file a [GitHub feature request issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues) to discuss it.

*[1] One could potentially create a custom extension Axis subclass to do this, but that would be non-trvial work, as `Axis` is one of the most complicated BokehJS objects.*